# Motion chart using nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to implement motion charts similar to http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/ but using nvd3.js. I took the example scatter/bubble chart from nvd3.org and added one additional key to the data. I use this key as a frame number for the animation. you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bartiosze/ny6vnznn/.

My idea was to change the data for the chart in a function called from .tween:

```
function drawFrame(idx) {
    var data = _.where(dataset, {
        index: idx
    });
    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data)
      .transition().duration(100).call(window.chart.update);
}
function tweener() {
    var idx = d3.interpolateNumber(0, 9);
    return function (t) {
        drawFrame(Math.round(idx(t)));
    };
}

//should this work?
d3.select('#chart svg')
  .transition().duration(10000).ease("linear").tween(".nv-clip-points", tweener);
```

It might be a general d3 question, but am I missing something?